# How to have rbenv include a Ruby version that was not installed thru rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

My command had created tool chains for a number of different tool including Ruby; it is an older version (1.9.3) and available from a network drive /company-tool/bin

I like to explore and learn some of the newer features of Ruby, so I installed v2.0.0 and v2.3.0 and I am using rbenv to manage them.

However, for the my company's tools/systems, I will need to use Ruby that is from /company-tool/bin and not from my rbenv.

Is there a way that I can configure/inject this 1.9.3 version of Ruby into rbenv such that I can use rbenv to switch between the locally installed Ruby and to my company's provided Ruby?

Or is there a better approach for this?

Comment: Wouldn't writing a bash script solve this? A script that would remove `rbenv` from the path and add `/company-tool/bin`'s ruby to the path and otherwise when you run it ?

Comment: You probably should recommend that they _NOT_ use 1.9.3. It's very out of date.

Answer (score 1):

`rbenv` simply looks for Ruby versions in `dirname $(rbenv prefix)` (usually `~/.rbenv/versions`). You can just symlink your Ruby into that directory.

Comment: Thank you...  That seems to be the easiest way to achieve what I want.